# SQL getting ordered row number per customer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database for a pet shop, and I'm trying to get the most bought pets per customer.  So if a customer bought `6 mice`, `3 birds`, `2 cats`, `3 dogs`, I'm trying to get the following:

```
Customer ID     Animal  Count
-----------     ------  -----
1               mouse   6
1               bird    3
1               dog     3
```

However, in order to do that, I need to group by animal and customer ID, and create a row number for each record by count.

I have 3 tables:

- Orders
- Order contents (i.e animals in the order)
- Animal details (i.e type of animal, cost, etc.)

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT customer_id, animal, count(*) as cnt, row_number() over (order by count(*)) as seqnum
FROM [Order_Contents] cc
INNER JOIN [Animals] p on cc.animal_id = p.animal_id
INNER JOIN [Orders] o ON cc.order_id = o.order_id 
WHERE customer_id = 1
GROUP BY animal, customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id, seqnum
```

Here is what I expect:

```
Customer ID     Animal  Count  seqnum
-----------     ------  -----  ------
1               mouse   6      1
1               bird    3      2
1               dog     3      3
1               cat     2      4
```

However, the sequential number isn't per customer, it's just sequential for the whole result set:

```
Customer ID     Animal  Count  seqnum
-----------     ------  -----  ------
1               mouse   6      98
1               bird    3      33
1               dog     3      36
1               cat     2      15
```

What am I doing wrong here? I need seqnum to be able to do "top 3" per customer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is getting the highest total for a customer with the details.

This returns the information:

```
SELECT o.customer_id, a.animal, COUNT(*) as cnt, 
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY o.customer_id) as customer_cnt
FROM Order_Contents cc INNER JOIN
     Animals a
     ON cc.animal_id = a.animal_id INNER JOIN
     Orders o ON cc.order_id = o.order_id 
WHERE customer_id = 1
GROUP BY animal, customer_id
ORDER BY customer_cnt DESC;
```

To get the details for the customer with the highest count, you can use the `TOP WITH TIES` trick:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES ca.*
FROM (SELECT o.customer_id, a.animal, COUNT(*) as cnt, 
             SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY o.customer_id) as customer_cnt
      FROM Order_Contents cc INNER JOIN
           Animals a
           ON cc.animal_id = a.animal_id INNER JOIN
           Orders o ON cc.order_id = o.order_id 
      WHERE customer_id = 1
      GROUP BY a.animal, o.customer_id
     ) ca
ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY customer_cnt DESC);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the partition so seq reset

```
 row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by count(*))
```